# Where is isc-dhcp-server configuration files in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: dhcp

On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I can not find the path to `isc-dhcp-server` as it is mentioned in several areas as in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221329/how-do-i-configure-dhcpd) (for Ubuntu 12.04).

It is installed on my machine, but I want to access its configuration files that I can not see.

Where can I find it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04, it should be `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`. The following command will list all installed files from `isc-dhcp-server` package and filter `/etc` configuration using `grep`.

```
$ dpkg -L isc-dhcp-server | grep /etc/

/etc/dhcp
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server
/etc/init
/etc/init/isc-dhcp-server.conf
/etc/init/isc-dhcp-server6.conf
/etc/apparmor.d
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd
/etc/apparmor.d/dhcpd.d
```

Through GUI, Open Synaptic: Right click on `isc-dhcp-server` → Properties → Installed Files.